# MS Graph Explorer does not return the expanded single valued extended property

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, mapi, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm unable to expand the single valued extended property of a calendar event using MS Graph Explorer.

Here is the query string that I enter: (I've URL encoded the spaces)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events('AAKT1CZJAAA=')?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'String%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20MyCustomData')
```

The following error is returned:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Parsing Select and Expand failed.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "54e97d07-1c6d-4cb5-8fd0-385dae4cb5b2",
        "date": "2020-05-28T14:31:44"
    }
}
```

I can't really detect what may be wrong with the syntax.

I've used OutlookSpy to make sure I had the right guid.

Any ideas?

**NOTE**
In order to verify that I was using the right Id I used the following query.  It ran successfully.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events('AAKT1CZJAAA=')?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep:ep/id%20eq%20'Integer%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20MyCustomData'%20and%20cast(ep/value,%20Edm.Int32)%20eq%2063531)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you get to the bottom of this?  In the first get request, you are looking for an id of type string, but in the one that works, you are looking for an Integer.

```
String%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20MyCustomData')
```

and then:

```
Integer%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20MyCustomData'%20and%20cast(ep/value,%20Edm.Int32)%20eq%2063531)
```